# download handler

Tags: r, shiny

with the help of this code i can download the text as a text what shoud i do to download the text as pdf

```
 library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text","Enter your text",""),
      downloadButton("report", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(("Text which we entered"),
              textOutput("mytext")
    ))))
```

#for server

```
     library(shiny)
library(markdown)
shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$mytext<-renderText(input$text)
  output$report<- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      "example.txt"
      },
    content = function(file) {
      #pdf(input$text, file)
      #render(input$text, pdf_document())
      #file.copy("www/teste.pdf", file)
      writelines(input$text,file)
    })
})
```

Comment: Could you tell more about "not working"? Is there an error message, or what?

Comment: i tried to open the pdf file but its saying like the file is corrupted @StéphaneLaurent

Answer (score 0):

The id of `downloadButton` must match the one of `downloadHandler`:

```
downloadButton("report", "Download")
```

Comment: still the file is corrupted

Comment: warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="NA": The system cannot find the file specified
Warning: running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "C:\Users\DATASC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSyIo9y\file664754f12e.tex"' had status 127
Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile C:\Users\DATASC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSyIo9y\file664754f12e.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/ i m getting this error while running this code @DaveArmstrong

Comment: i need a app like if i enter a text whatever it should be download as pdf  @DaveArmstrong

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want the text file to look like, but this worked for me:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text","Enter your text",""),
      downloadButton("report", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(("Text which we entered"),
              textOutput("mytext")
    ))))


#for server

library(shiny)
library(markdown)
server <- function(input,output){
  report_yaml <- '
---
title: "Test Report"
author: "Dave Armstrong"
date: "11/3/2020"
output: pdf_document
---
'
  output$mytext<-renderText(input$text)
  output$report<- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.pdf", 
    content = function(file) {
      cat(report_yaml, input$text, sep="\n", file="report.Rmd")
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                      params = params,
                      envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    
    })
}
```

[image]

[image]